# I can't successfully chain my route handlers?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I've got a node.js/express app I'm working on and routes that look like-

`app.post('/user/:who/update', isLoggedIn, userUpdate.save);`

inside userUpdate.save I'm calling `res.redirect` or `res.render` (different routes but same idea). I don't like this. I'd like to keep my res.* calls in routes.js, but when I attempt this

`app.post('/user/:who/update', isLoggedIn, userUpdate.save, function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('/user/'+req.user.local.username);
});`

with a call to `next(req, res)` at the end of `userUpdate.save`, the `res.redirect` function isn't called. What I think `next()` is, does not seem to be what it actually is. What am  I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The call to `next()` bypasses the remainder of your callbacks.

See this ref http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.post.method

Take a look at this example and alternately comment out each of the `next()` calls (and then both of them) and watch where the execution flows.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/test', function(req, res, next){
    console.log('/test callback1');
    next('route');
    //next();
}, function(res, res, next){
    console.log('/test callback2');
    res.send('sent from /test/cb2')
});

app.get('/test', function(req, res){
    console.log('response from /test route handler 2');
    res.send('sent from /test route handler 2');
})

var server = app.listen(8911, function (s) {
  console.log('Listening on port ', server.address().port);

});
```

Comment: What am I misunderstanding about this then?-- A route can be handled using a more than one callback function (make sure to specify the next object):
`app.get('/example/b', function (req, res, next) {
  console.log('response will be sent by the next function ...');
  next();
}, function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello from B!');
});`